# Easiest way to append a string with different values by checking if hiddenfields are empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, audit-trail, hiddenfield

I'm building an audit trail in C#, asp.net. On the .aspx page I have several hidden fields which associate themselves with regular fields (i.e. txtFirstName -> firstNameTrackerHiddenField). I have it set up so that when the user inputs/selects data to a field, the hidden field gets a value set to it. Example:

```
    protected void txtFirstName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.FirstNameTrackerHiddenField.Value = "1";
    }
```

Now to build my Audit Log I was thinking of just checking through each hidden field, pulling the ones that aren't null, and appending a string, depending on which field the user has inputed/changed. I could do a bunch of nested if statements but that would be really sloppy.
Sorry if I'm not making any sense, I'm still a little new to the coding world and I thought this methodology would be pretty neat and easy to implement. Here's what I have so far in the auditLog method:

```
    protected string auditLogString()
    {
        string auditLog = this.txtAuditLogReadOnly.Text + System.Environment.NewLine + System.Environment.NewLine + 
            DateTime.Now.ToString() + "- (Incident saved by: " + Page.User.Identity.Name + ") ";

        if (this.FirstNameTrackerHiddenField.Value != string.Empty)
        {
            auditLog += "- with changes to First Name."
            if (this.LastNameTrackerHiddenField.Value != string.Empty)
            {
                auditLog += "- with changes to Last Name."
            }
        }

        return auditLog;
    }
```

And the list goes on. There's about 50 fields to cycle through, so that's why I was wondering if there was a better way to go about this... Thanks for any input, and please don't be rough with me... :)

Comment: You dont have to check anything - simply if you dont want to add anything make the added string "" else change the added string to your text. Set the string in method textChanged. OR you can have an bool array and string array, you can interate throught the bool array and if true add string of same index from string array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner way to if/else-ing every `HiddenField` would be to loop through the controls on your page, check their type and if they're a `HiddenField` with a value, do something with the value.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is HiddenField)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((ctrl as HiddenField).Value))
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did it!! So what I did was instead of adding a value of 1 into the hidden field I added what I was going to concatenate instead. So the loop went through and pulled out all the values of the hidden field and there we are!! Audit trail!! JAZZ HANDS!! thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a few things here. First - try not to do string concatenation using + in C#, unless you're concatenating constant expressions (which DateTime.Now and Page.User.Identity.Name are not). Use a StringBuilder instead. Strings in C# are immutable.

Second, you can just add a custom attribute to your textboxes and collect their value server-side; there's no need for additional hidden fields.

So, given an example form like: -

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAuditLogReadOnly" runat="server" />
        <div id="divContainer" runat="server">

            <asp:TextBox ID="t1" runat="server" fieldname="First Name" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="t2" runat="server" fieldname="Last Name" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="t3" runat="server" fieldname="Shoe Size" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="t4" runat="server" fieldname="Banana" />

        </div>
```

(Note 'fieldname' attribute)
You could scrape the values into your audit log like so: -

```
        var builder = new StringBuilder(
            string.Format("{0}{1}{2:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm}- (Incident saved by: {3})",
                txtAuditLogReadOnly.Text,
                Environment.NewLine,
                DateTime.Now,
                Page.User.Identity.Name));

        var controls = from Control c in divContainer.Controls
                       select c;

        foreach (var ctl in controls)
        {
            if (ctl is TextBox)
            {
                var txt = (TextBox)ctl;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt.Text))
                {
                    string fieldname = txt.Attributes["fieldname"];
                    builder.AppendFormat(" - with changes to {0}", fieldname);
                }
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString();
```

Comment: I can see how this would work. Thanks for the input I greatly appreciate it.